# Remove all files and directories older than 5 days except for one file

Tags: bash

Using the **find** command I'd like to remove all directories located at `/home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Downstream` which are more than 5 days old having in mind that:

1. All the files inside directories should also be removed.
2. We should not remove the file `/home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Downstream/download.sh` even though it is more than 5 days old.

Here is the script I have today but I think it also deletes the download.sh file above since it has no exception

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Downstream -mtime +5 -type d -exec rm -rv {} +
```

Is there a way to add this exception so that we do not need to write a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
find /home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Downstream/* ! -name "download.sh" -mtime +5 -type d -exec rm -rv {} +
```

notice the:

```
! -name "download.sh"
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: it would avoid deleting `download.sh` files anywhere in the subdirectories though, which could be a problem. I guess you should use the `-path` test to avoid that.

Comment: My entire `/home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Downstream` folder has now been removed!

Comment: @Disasterkid you mean probably the contents within your `/home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Downstream` directory

Comment: "relevant username" Oh wait this isn't reddit.

Comment: @nbari together with the `Downstream` folder. I don't know why it removes that as well.

Comment: @Disasterkid nu11po1n73r's answer explains it well : the `Downstream` directory itself is matched since it's a directory and isn't named `download.sh`. So it is `rm -rf`ed. Always try a `find` without any action first ;)

Answer (score 2):

I guess the issue that you are facing is that when you do,

```
find /home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Downstream
```

It ends up listing `/home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Downstream` as well and then the `rm` command deletes the main directory as well. What you can do instead is

```
find /home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Downstream/* -mtime +5 -type d -exec rm -rv {} +
```

The `*` prevents the parent from listing.

---

Or in short you can also write,

```
$ find /home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Downstream -mindepth 1 -mtime +5 -type d -delete
```

- `-mindepth 1` Will discard the parent folder.
- `-type d` Selects only directories
- `-delete` Deletes the selected nodes

Comment: @Aaron I guess the issue is something else, because `type` should have prevented the `download.sh` from listing. I have updated the answer. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: You're right, I hadn't though of that. Your current answer looks great, now for OP to find a way to recover his lost files...

Comment: and what about the exception (the `download.sh` file)?

Comment: @Disasterkid The `type d` will select only directories. So it will not list `download.sh` Try without the delete to see what files/directories are affected

Comment: Another alternative (but without much interest in this case) would be to use the `-mindepth 1` option to avoid matching the directory passed to `find`

Comment: @Aaron Ohh nice. I hope you don't mind me stealing that for the answer. Was thinking of `cd && find`. But `mindepth` is much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

**-not -path** is  used for ignoring the files/directories for find

```
find /home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Downstream/* -not -path '/home/ubuntu/pub/sfmc/Downstream/download.sh' -mtime +5 -type d -exec rm -rv {} +
```